# Mysql: Group by symbol but retain all top target value rows

Tags: mysql

The below data is just an abstract of my original data ,formed by 'join' of four tables. The requirement is ;

```
data :
 symbol  target  analyst
    a       1690    peas
    a       1230    tomato
    a       1235    papaya
    a       1230    papaya
    a       1690    apple 
    b       1450    bean
    b       1914    potato
    b       1540    tomato
    b       1797    papaya
    b       1880    apple 
    b       2000    turnips
    c       1550    bean
    c       1588    onion
    c       1588    onion
    c       1588    potato
    c       1463    soya
    c       1130    tomato
```

> ```
>    required :
>    symbol  target  analyst
>       a         1690     peas
>       a         1690     apple 
>       b         2000     turnips
>       c         1588     onion
>       c         1588     potato
> ```

i.e. for each symbol in the table,the rows for max(target) for each unique analyst has to be displayed .
Tried using combination of 'max(target)' and 'group by symbol' , which displays only one maximum target row .
A part of the code used to form data is ;

```
SELECT 
     a.symbol, c.target, c.analyst 
FROM table1 a
     LEFT JOIN table2 b 
         ON a.symbol = b.symbol 
     LEFT JOIN table3 c 
         ON a.symbol LIKE CONCAT('%', c.symbol , '%')
     LEFT JOIN table4 d 
         ON a.symbol = d.symbol;
```

Comment: I guess in required data set for first row it should be `Axis Direct` instead if `peas` ?

Comment: What's your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: Show your schema of the 3 tables, and the join you use to get the sample data shown in your question.

Comment: @sloan-thrasher, find the edit above in code

Comment: You still need to show the schema's of those tables.

Comment: all the symbol column are of type varchar so is analyst . target is of type decimal . the primary key for each of these tables is 'sn' which is of type int (auto-increment) . Is this sufficient ?

Comment: @Me-si what is the purpose of `table4 d` when there no selection and no operation is performed using table4 ? Also provide your table definitions with relevant sample data set

Comment: @m-khalid-junaid: as i mentioned above this is just an abstract of my original purpose code , in which i use table4

Answer (score 1):

To get the desired out put you can do self join

```
select distinct a.*
from demo a 
left join demo b on a.symbol = b.symbol
                 and a.target < b.target
where b.symbol is null
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b78522/2)

Comment: The data is from join of three tables , how do i Apply self join ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a join against a select that get the max target for each symbol:

```
SELECT
    a.symbol,
    a.target,
    a.analyst
FROM data a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT b.symbol,MAX(b.target) as `maxval` FROM data b GROUP BY b.symbol) b
ON b.symbol = a.symbol AND b.`maxval` = a.target
ORDER BY a.symbol,a.target,a.analyst
```

Comment: The data above is formed by join of three tables

Comment: You might create a view of the 3 table join, then use the SQL above.